# Scheduled task error

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am getting error in scheduled task :"http://localhost:4625/DataUpdater.aspx.Error Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Scheduledtask vbs script :

```
Call LogEntry()

Sub LogEntry()

    On Error Resume Next        

    Dim objRequest
    Dim URL

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    URL = "http://localhost:4625/DataUpdater.aspx"

    objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

    objRequest.Send

    Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is coming back from Cassini/IIS then you should post the code in the .aspx / .aspx.cs file, and the line the error is occurring on.

Comment: When i run it manually,it works.The issue is only with scheduled task.

Comment: Is the error in the website or the vbscript?  Often scheduled task issues are related to permissions and which account the task is running under.

Comment: The VBScript is ok.The error is in the dataupdater page.I have used Session state in Page_Load().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a batch file to do this?

For example here are some sample run lines:

```
cscript.exe c:\scripts\call_logs.vbs
```

Or:

```
script.exe c:\scripts\call_logs.vbs
```

Here is one that I use to archive off IIS Logs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscript.exe D:\scripts\list.vbs
```